# How to compare multiple strings within in the same list in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to write a Haskell function that takes in a list of strings, compares all the strings in the list, and outputs a list of strings that are of the longest length. I want to do this without any predefined functions or imports, I want to try and figure it out all recursively. For example:

```
    longeststrings["meow","cats","dog","woof"] -> ["meow","cats","woof"]
```

I know it is a silly example, but I think it proves the point.

I want to do something like

```
    longeststrings:: [string] -> [string]
    longeststrings []          = []
    longeststrings [x:xs]      = if (x > xs) x:longeststrings[xs]
```

But I don't know how to only take the largest size strings out of the list, or remove the smallest ones. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could trivially keep track of the longest length string and an accumulator of values of that length.

```
longestStrings :: [String] -> [String]
longestStrings = go [] 0
  where
  go acc _ []       = acc  -- base case
  go acc n (x:xs)
    | length x > n  = go [x] (length x) xs
    -- if x is longer than the previously-seen longest string, then set
    -- accumulator to the list containing only x, set the longest length
    -- to length x, and keep looking
    | length x == n = go (x:acc) n xs
    -- if x is the same length as the previously-seen longest string, then
    -- add it to the accumulator and keep looking
    | otherwise     = go acc n xs
    -- otherwise, ignore it
```

or, as Davislor rightly mentions in the comments, this can be implemented as a fold by teaching the helper function to determine its own longest length

```
longestStrings :: [String] -> [String]
longestStrings = foldr f []
  where
  f x []        = [x]
  f x yss@(y:_) =
    case compare (length x) (length y) of
      GT -> [x]
      EQ -> x : yss
      LT -> yss
```

Comment: That would be perfect without using where... is it possible to do it without? Also, would you mind explaining a bit more on what acc is here? Or how it is working throughout? I am a bit confused with it.

Comment: You don’t even need the extra length argument. If the accumulator is non-empty, the head is (in a tie for) the longest string encountered, so you can take `(length . head) acc`. Then it could just be a `fold`.

Comment: @Davislor good call RE: fold. I was just trying to build an overly-complicated Stateful action to do the same.

Comment: @PushedCrayon `where` is not something you should be avoiding if you're writing Haskell at any level. `acc` is the accumulator, or the list that gets built as you find more strings that count.

Comment: @PushedCrayon One way to avoid `where` is to write the helper as a lambda, but I’d say that would be more complex. The helper has a different signature than the original function, so it’s got to be separate, and it’s used only inside this function, so it should be nested.

Comment: @AdamSmith, I am trying to avoid using where because I am trying to get more familiar with functional programming in general, and I have read a lot that using things such as where and let are too close to imperative programming. So I am trying to think of how I could create two separate functions here to get rid of the where. Do you have any ideas? Also, thank you for clarifying acc, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: Oh no, `where` is totally good functional style. I’m tempted now to write another example.

Comment: @PushedCrayon "I have read a lot that using things such as where and let are too close to imperative programming." Stop reading things from those places, that's nonsense :)

Comment: @Davislor could you possibly write one without using where or anything? I am curious as to what it would look like. But I understand if you don't feel like it.

Comment: @AdamSmith I appreciate all of your help! Its hard to know what is or isn't good to read when it comes to new languages and such. But thank you for your insight :)

Comment: @PushedCrayon you'd just write `go` (or `f` in my new example) as a toplevel function, but since it serves no purpose whatsoever at top level, that makes worse code not better.

Comment: @PushedCrayon this comment section is getting crowded. If you have any other questions I should be around for another half hour or so in [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164861/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-48713997-how-to-compare-multiple-strings-with) give a holler.

Answer (score 2):

As requested, here’s a version with and without the use of `where`.  I think this is a good demonstration of why the advice not to use `where` is bad advice.  I think the first version is a lot easier to understand.

Keep in mind, functional programming isn’t a monastic vow to forswear certain keywords out of masochism.  Nor is it a checklist of fashion tips (`where` is *so* last season!).  “You should avoid that construct arbitrarily because it’s not the ‘functional’ thing to do” really is not how it works.  So you shouldn’t uglify your code for the sake of a tip like that.

It *is* often a good idea to follow the same coding style as other programmers so they will find it easier to understand you.  (For example, Adam Smith was subtly trying to train you that `acc` is a common name for an accumulator and `go` a common name for a recursive helper function, and they help other programmers figure out the pattern he’s using.)  But in fact Haskell programmers do use `where`, a lot.

Anyway, the code:

```
longeststrings :: [String] -> [String]
{- Filters all strings as long as any other in the list. -}
longeststrings = foldr go []
  where
    go x [] = [x]
    go x leaders | newlength > record  = [x]
                 | newlength == record = x:leaders
                 | otherwise           = leaders
      where
        record = (length . head) leaders
        newlength = length x

longestStringsUsingLambda :: [String] -> [String]
longestStringsUsingLambda = foldr
    (\x leaders ->
       if leaders == [] then [x]
       else case compare (length x) (length $ head leaders) of
         GT -> [x]
         EQ -> x:leaders
         LT -> leaders )
    []

main :: IO ()
main = let testcases = [ ["meow","cats","dog","woof"],
                         ["foo","bar","baz"],
                         ["meep","foo","bar","baz","fritz","frotz"]
                       ]
       in foldMap print $
          map longestStringsUsingLambda testcases
```

You can try eliminating the `let testcases =` ... and see if you consider that an improvement.